# Standard/common term for SQL functions/operators (never) throwing exceptions

Tags: sql

There are many SQL functions/operators that are under certain circumstances throw exceptions.

**Examples:**

- The division operator (/) throws a data exception if the divisor is zero.
- The NTILE function throws an exception if the number of tiles is less than or equal to zero.
- The CAST function throws an exception when the conversion leads to loss of precision.

There are also other SQL functions/operators that will never throw an exception.

SQL engines may have slightly different semantics about when (and if) an operator/function throws but what is of interest here is the terminology and not what happens for each database.

What is the right term to describe SQL operator/functions that:

- may throw exceptions under certain circumstances
- never throw exceptions no matter the input

Comment: What is your question here? What RDBMS are you *really* asking about; you've tagged 4 different one's here and they all behave **very** differently. You seem to be using [so] like a blogging site here; it's not a blog it's a Q&A site.

Comment: Different DBMS communities may use different terms to describe/refer to those kind of functions and that's exactly why I tagged multiple engines.

Comment: Then why tag any of them if your question (which is what? you haven't explained) if your question is about none of them? Just tag [[tag:sql]]. Or, perhaps you're asking about [[tag:ansi-sql]]? You are certainly not asking about MySQL, *and* SQL Server, *and* PostgreSQL, *and* Oracle.

Comment: @zabetak again, what is the question? There's no specific kind of function. Bad data is bad data, period. Your "answer" shows a bit of confusion about SQL and data processing

Comment: When performing various database optimization techniques (like filter pushdown, or short-circuit evaluation, or constant folding) it is important to know if a function/operator can throw an exception or not. Having a term to describe these category of functions is important.

Comment: @zabetak fun fact about dialects - none offers full compliance with the ANSI standard. A function that wouldn't cause an error in one dialect would do so in another. The one that doesn't throw is considered HUGELY UNSAFE because it would hide actual bad data or processing behind a default value. `1/0` should throw, not return NULL.

Comment: `When performing various database optimization techniques` those are performed by the database engine, which already knows how its functions behave. Again, there are no specific rules. Especially in type conversions, one database can throw where another implicitly converts from one type to another

Comment: The main question remains. I am looking for an appropriate term to describe functions that throw or never throw exceptions. I am implementing a query optimizer and I want to use the correct/best terminology when I define the rules. Of-course I can invent a new word myself but why not using an existing one if there is.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the SQL standard I couldn't find a term describing such operators/functions so there may not be a standardized term to refer to them. I tried to see if there are DBMS specific terms that are widely used but couldn't find something either.

I know that in [Apache Calcite](https://calcite.apache.org/) community, some used the term *unsafe* [1, 2] to describe functions that may throw exceptions although I wouldn't recommend using it cause it is quite broad.

It seems that in mathematics they use the term *undefined* [3] to refer to expressions which do not have an actual representation (such as division by zero). Nevertheless, I would only use the term *undefined* to describe a specific evaluation of the function and not the function in general. Saying that division or CAST is undefined sounds weird and incorrect.

In C++, the term *noexcept* [4] is used to describe functions that never throw exceptions. So far this is the best term that I could find for describing functions that never throw and I think we can borrow it in the SQL community if there isn't a better one.

Lastly in the Java world, we have *throwable* [5] methods.This could be another term to use in the SQL world for describing those functions/operators that may throw.

**References**

- [1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-2731
- [2] https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/cbbe5701b7f61d7f8df12d314ba5aabf898c1cae/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/rex/RexSimplify.java#L1392
- [3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_(mathematics)
- [4] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec
- [5] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html

Comment: There's no term because it's not needed. SQL isn't C++ or mathematics. Functions that throw in SQL aren't unsafe, quite the opposite. Even in C++, exception safety typically almost always means *not* hiding exceptions, but ensuring they're propagated without causing side-effects

Comment: Besides, this isn't an answer. It helps explain the question, but this is no answer

Comment: The first paragraph effectively states "I don't know the answer" and the other paragraphs are answering a different question of what other languages call the term and are not relevant to the question regarding SQL.

Comment: The first paragraph says that SQL standard does not define a term. The other three paragraphs introduce terms which can be used to describe throwing/not throwing functions.

Comment: They describe terms that are used in *other* languages for such functions, @zabetak , not what they are called in T-SQL, PL/SQL, etc. They are *suggestions* for what the dialects could call them at best. You might as well make your own suggestion at the same time. How about "Risky" functions for one's that could cause an error, because you're taking a risk they error.  Or perhaps for functions that don't error could be "Hidey" functions, as they hide any error(s) that might occur.

Comment: "The first paragraph says that SQL standard does not define a term." That is not what the first paragraph says; it says "I couldn't find a term" which is a different statement.

Comment: I didn't write the SQL standard so I cannot be 100% sure that there is nothing there. I did search for every occurrence of error/exception and other similar words and couldn't find what I was looking for. There are certainly people who know the standard better than me so maybe they have to add something more or just confirm that what I wrote is true.